# combine notEqual and In operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is to update all the rows where userName not equal to 'santhosh' and 'girish'.

```
update DB set Username = 'Other' where Username <> in ('santhosh' , 'girish');
```

but this is not correct query. can anyone help me with how to achieve this?

Comment: `Username NOT IN()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To turn the [**correct comment by HoneyBadger**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587819/honeybadger) into an answer:

In this case you can use the `NOT` syntax.

```
update DB set Username = 'Other' where Username NOT IN ('santhosh' , 'girish');
```